# Add comment to Github pull request from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-api, github-enterprise

I am wondering if there is already a way to update a Github (Enterprise) pull request with a comment within the Jenkins Pipeline syntax. I have it already updating it with the build status of success or failed automatically but I also want to post a comment with the test results and code coverage or the reason why the build failed. Before I start to write my own function in groovy calling the REST API of github to do this I wanted to make sure there wasn't already an easier way say like a plugin that had this function.

Answer (score 11):

Check first if the ["Adding a comment" section](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin#adding-a-comment) of the **[jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin)** would work for you:

```
def comment = pullRequest.comment('This PR is highly illogical..')
```

There are however issues associated with that approach ([#85](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin/issues/85), [#33](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin/issues/33))

Check however that you have the [pipeline-github](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-github) installed first.

Comment: Has anyone tried this approach? I encountered the error mentioned in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50488566/5362795

Comment: Does not work !

Comment: @DominicHofer Would the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488566/add-a-comment-in-github-pull-request-in-jenkins#comment111502714_50516024 apply in your case?