# Add a comment in github pull request in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I am using Git pull request builder plugin in Jenkins to link the Pull requests to Jenkins. Jobs are triggered with hooks and everything runs smoothly.

Nevertheless, at the end of the build, I'd like to add a comment when there's a fail/success or an error.

I tried using pipeline and use

```
pullRequest.comment('This is a comment sent from the Pipeline')
```

But it doesn't recognize it (I installed pipeline for github):

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pullRequest for class: groovy.lang.Binding
  at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
  at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:5)
  at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor446.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
  at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

With the freestyle job:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.pullrequest.utils.JobHelper.getGhRepositoryFromPRTrigger(JobHelper.java:162)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.pullrequest.utils.JobHelper.getGhPullRequest(JobHelper.java:178)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.pullrequest.publishers.impl.GitHubPRCommentPublisher.perform(GitHubPRCommentPublisher.java:72)
  at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
  at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1752)
  at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'GitHub PR: post comment' marked build as failure
```

Now I don't really know where to look for

Comment: it must be multibranch pipepline. If you use multibranch pipepline then you will not get this error message and you need to include libraries for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a plugin doing it, so I did using curl. Here is my groovy function

```
def call(def text_pr) {
  def repository_url = scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url
  def repository_name = repository_url.replace("git@github.com:","").replace(".git","")

  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '<YOUR-TOKEN-ID>', variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]) {
    sh "curl -s -H \"Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}\" -X POST -d '{\"body\": \"${text_pr}\"}' \"https://api.github.com/repos/${repository_name}/issues/${ghprbPullId}/comments\""
  }
}
```

Comment: `pullRequest` is available when github branch source plugin is used to build pull requests. (Branch source plugin is what powers the scm features for multibranch pipelines). It's not available in ghprb plugin.