# How to Post PR comment from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am running Multibranch pipeline jobs using Github plugin with the option below
[image: Discover branches]

and periodical polling (5 mins) to look for open pull requests (new feature branches in our case). Open pull request is identified, job is triggered and on successful completion am able to update the status. would like to add a PR status message with URL using

> `pullRequest.comment('This is a comment sent from the Pipeline').`

But pipeline job fails with

> "No such property: pullRequest for class: groovy.lang.Binding".

on further inspection, **env.CHANGE_ID** is set to NULL (means it is not a PR build job which is a prerequisite to use pullRequest module). can anyone suggest some idea to get CHANGE_ID set or means to post/update comments to PR other than success or Fail

Comment: I do this posting to github's api with `httpRequest`. In case you are interested I can show you my snippet

Comment: @gmc would be really helpful. I looked at doing it via curl as mentioned here 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488566/add-a-comment-in-github-pull-request-in-jenkins' but i do not use the ghprb plugin hence ${ghprbPullId} is not set too in my case.

Comment: well, my snippet will only work if you have the PR id

Comment: @gmc. can I post the comments against the Commit SHA!!! which i can get via $GIT_COMMIT

Comment: have corrected the answer removing the ext link and adding the piece of code.